# Multi column dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu with 30+ items, is there already a way to get Bootstrap to show the menu using 3 columns instead of one really tall one or does this require some customization?

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2965

Comment: Sigh. I wish this wasn't closed, I could really use the answer, and that link is just to a closed case!

Comment: What a pitty, I'd like to have this too.

Comment: Why is this closed?  Could this please be re-opened :-/

Comment: Found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/twitter-bootstrap/IK6QcJpLMXI/sVgHdttwHm4J

Comment: Looking for this answer too... why closed? WHY? Look at the views of this question!

Comment: It is entirely inappropriate to close this question Robert.  "Small geographic area" or "narrow situation"?  I think that you are abusing the privileges that the community has granted to you in closing this (very useful) question.