# bootstrap / html5 dropdown menu with multiple columns

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, multiple-columns

Is it possible to have drop-down menus with multiple columns in bootstrap 2.x I know it was not in 1.x?

I think from ui perspective when you have more then 10, 20 or even 30 links in the bootstrap drop-down menu it goes down out the fold or visible area of the page, I think it would make sense being able to have multiple columns.

It would look way better to have two rows of ten or some other combination using multiple columns.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: If you do have a question, it looks like it has already been asked before - and closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285408/multi-column-dropdown-menu

Comment: That was asked and closed in july 2012 when bootstrap was on a much earlier version but thanks I did however find a way to do it but breaks in mobile

Comment: Care to share your solution? Inquiring minds would like to know ;-)